# Does private inheritance actually create a base-class object in the derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

In C++ Primer Plus p.797,

> Containment adds an object to a class as a named member object, whereas private inheritance adds an object to a class as an unnamed inherited object.

I wonder if "private inheritance actually create a base-class object in the derived class" as this book said,
Or is it just a conceptual explanation??

Comment: The book is right, of course. If the inherited object is not a part of the derived object, in some way, then where is it? It's a Scooby-Doo mystery!

Comment: Yes, what the book states is actually true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is basically correct, but requires some corrections in the C++ terminology if it is taken strictly. (However, especially when the point is to explain OOP concepts, this terminology is often not used strictly or even conflicts with OOP terminology.)

It is not the class which contains a member object or an inherited object. It is each *object of the class type* which contains a member *subobject* or a *base class subobject*. On the other hand the class itself has *members* and *base classes* corresponding to these *subobjects*.

It is also not clear to me why `private` is of any relevance here. It doesn't affect the statement at all. As mentioned under this answer it might just be meant to contrast the "*containment*" concept which I guess in the C++ language would translate to private non-static data members. The quote probably is missing context though as well.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. (I think that the book wants to explain difference between private inheritance and containment,,)